# Need help understanding why this 1d string array can be declared like a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I'm making use of collision detection code from [Programmer's Ranch](https://www.programmersranch.com/2014/10/c-basics-snake-game-in-ascii-art-part-3.html) to learn more about making ASCII games and among the collision detection is this:

```
 if (next.X == location.X && next.Y == location.Y || grid[next.X][next.Y] == 'X')
                {
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                }
```

location and next are keeping track of the x and y coordinates of the ASCII characters, for a game of snake in this instance. What stumps me, is that grid is defined as a 1d string array with several "X"s in it to define a playing field as follows:

```
static string[] grid = new string[]
{
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"x            x",
"x            x",
"x            x",
"x            x",
"x            x",
"x            x",
"x            x",
"x            x",
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

However, I don't understand how grid can be used with the syntax grid[next.X][next.Y] or really even how it accomplishes results. I understand that X and Y are being used to calculate whether the player's ASCII avatar has collided with any 'X' chars, as they define the playing field, but the syntax confuses me.

Comment: Hint: `"hello"[4]` will give you `'o'`.

Comment: String's characters can be accessed (read-only) with its [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars)

Comment: By the way, when you say "like a 2d array", you actually mean "like a jagged array" (C# has both - jagged is `[1][2]`, whereas 2d is `[1,2]`)

Comment: Ahh that makes so much sense, thank you two for taking the time to answer my question! And yeah you're right, I had forgotten about jagged arrays actually, I was making this more complicated in my head than it was in reality.